# Last <li> Not Inline, Messes up the Size of it

Tags: html, css, html-lists

So for my webpage I am making a dropdown menu from scratch. So I have a header which contains 5 list items and a logo. Let's call the list items tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4 and tab5. My goal is to have tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4 and the logo display inline, but have tab5 display right below tab4. To do this, I set the first 4 tabs and the logo to have have the property display: inline-block and the 5th tab to be just display: block. This solves the issue of having the fifth tab display under the other tabs and the logo, though the fifth tab does not retain the same width as the other tabs, even though they are classified under the same class .tab. What ends up happening is the fifth tab becomes the width of the body. I tried to fix this by setting the left and right padding of the tab manually, though this does not work. Is there a way I can have the fifth tab act/display exactly like the other tabs (as in same width, height, etc.), just not displayed inline?

Here's my html:

```
<div class="header">
    <a class="tab" id="tab1"><li>Home</li></a>
    <a class="tab" id="tab2"><li>About</li></a>
    <img src="images/logo.png" id="logo" width="260px" height="95px;"/>
    <a class="tab" id="tab3"><li>Menu</li></a>
    <a class="tab" id="tab4"><li>Order</li></a>
    <a class="tab" id="tab5"><li>Cater</li></a>
</div>
```

And here's my css:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.header{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}
.tab, #logo{
    padding-right: 2.4%;
    padding-left: 2.4%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
#tab5{
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/gobtt6vk/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#tab5` is occupying 100% of the `body`'s `width` because that's what `display:block;` does.

You can solve this problem by giving it a `width`, for example:

```
#tab5 {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto; /* this aligns #tab5 to center and also gives margin-top:10px; */
}
```

Or you can solve it by giving it a `display:table;` instead of `display:block;` so you wont need to give it a fixed `width`, it will adjust itself to the text.
Also your HTML structure should be improved, so I wasted a little bit of time here and reorganized it for you.

Here's an online example: https://jsfiddle.net/wujncnsd/

```
<div class="header">
    <ul>
        <li id="tab1" class="tab"><a>Home</a></li>
        <li id="tab2" class="tab"><a>About</a></li>
        <li id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" width="260" height="95"/>
        </li>
        <li id="tab3" class="tab"><a>Menu</a></li>
        <li id="tab4" class="tab"><a>Order</a></li>
        <li id="tab5" class="tab"><a>Cater</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
ul {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
li {list-style-type: none;}

.header{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}
.tab, #logo{
    padding-right: 2.4%;
    padding-left: 2.4%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
#tab5{
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: Ok turns out I was wrong, this doesn't do exactly what I want. It makes it so the tab doesn't display as having 100% width, but it removes all the padding that was defined in the .tab section of my CSS, as display: table ignores any padding previously given to it. Also giving it a fixed width messes with the text-align: center. Is there way to preserve padding as well and everything in the .tab section aswell? @Chun

Comment: @Robbie:  Since you want the buttons to be the same width, use a `width` style instead of relying on `padding` to do the work.  Adding `.tab {padding: 0; width: 4em; box-sizing: border-box;}` to @Chun's CSS solves the problem:  https://jsfiddle.net/8j3rpc5n/

Comment: Ok, I don't know why when I tried giving it a set width (as he Chun said in his answer) the text-align got messed up but now that I tried it again, it's working. Hmm. Either way, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

try this updated code ...

CSS:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.header{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}
.tab, #logo{
    padding-right: 2.4%;
    padding-left: 2.4%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
#tab5{
    margin-top: 5p;
}
```

Comment: i update my answer on my codepen, im sorry, but try that css

Comment: This doesn't seem to help any way in solving his problem @Anonymous nor the `Codepen` example previously posted (which was clearly off-topic and had nothing to do with this question), the only thing this code does is adding a `margin-top:5px;` to `#tab5`

Comment: i removed your display:block; on your #tab5